# subscribed event not firing due to null reference

Tags: c#

I am getting null reference error in the toPickedImage method and i dont understand why that is. Anyone can help me in explaining why i am reciving this error.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Code as follows:

```
public partial class ownGUI : UserControl
{
    private string m_id;
    private int m_value;

    public event EventHandler<GameEventArgs> Pickedimage;

    public ownGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ownGUI(String id, int value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_id = id;
        m_value = value;            
        GameEventArgs image = new GameEventArgs(m_id, m_value);
        toPickedimage(image);       

    }

    public void toPickedimage(GameEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Pickedimage != null) 
        {
            Pickedimage(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

//Regards

Comment: minor observation: why raise an event in the constructor? by definition, no calling code has got a reference to the object yet, so nobody could have *possibly* subscribed to the event at that point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems very unlikely, but there is an *extreme edge case* that will only happen during highly-threaded-code, and even then very rarely - however *it is technically possible* to get a thread-race in your implementation. It would be better to have:

```
var handler = Pickedimage
if(handler != null) handler(this, e);
```

However! I think it is far more likely that the **subscribed event** is raising this error due to a bug in the subscriber. Look at the stack-trace to find out. If you wanted to go overboard guarding the event (so it can't fail, even with bad subscribers), then something like:

```
var handler = Pickedimage;
if(handler != null) {
    foreach (EventHandler<GameEventArgs> subscriber in
        handler.GetInvocationList())
    {
        try {
            subscriber(this, e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Trace(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As a footnote, *personally* I would defer creating the `GameEventArgs` until you know you have someone who cares, for example:

```
protected virtual void OnPickedimage(int id, int value)
{
    var handler = Pickedimage;
    if(handler != null) {
        var e = new GameEventArgs(id, value);
        //... and invoke it 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Marc Gravell** pointed out the correct approach and solution in case if you are using your control in heavily multi-threaded scenario. With that clean knowledge, I am curious to know whether do you have any subscriber to your event when you first notice this null reference. This is for the simple and basic fact that , you will get null reference if you have no subscriber attached to that event.

```
public event EventHandler<GameEventArgs> Pickedimage= delegate { };
```

Comment: i have subscribed to it in an instance of a control in form1. control.PickedImage += onPickedImage;  And there is a method called onPickedImage().

Comment: I moved the code just to another class and it worked perfectly..I am very curios as to why it did not fire in the user control thou.